# MySQL Count multiple distinct records with condition

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I have a table that records all user cross-profile visits and I need to get the count of distinct visits and the count of new visits to a specified profile (:user_id) since the specified UNIX timestamp (:time).

```
id  | user_id  | visitor_id |  time (unix)
====+==========+============+=============
  1 |     1    |       5    |  1300000000
  2 |     1    |       5    |  1300000010
  3 |     1    |       8    |  1300000015
  4 |     1    |       9    |  1300000020
  5 |     1    |       9    |  1300000025
  6 |     1    |       9    |  1300000030
```

So far I was only able to get the count of total visits, but am unable to get the new ones.

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT v.visitor_id) AS total, SUM(v.time > 1300000012) AS new FROM profile_visits v WHERE v.user_id = 1`

returns

```
total | new
============
   3  |   4
```

but the required result is

```
total | new
============
   3  |   2
```

Comment: check the query that i have written below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want `SUM(v.time > 1300000012) AS new`.

The expression is either 0 or 1.  `COUNT()` will count 0 as happily as 1.  But `SUM()` will "count" only the 1's.

---

Re your comment:

```
SELECT COUNT(t.visitor_id) AS total, SUM(t.subtotal_new) AS total_new
FROM (SELECT v.visitor_id, SUM(v.time > 1300000012) AS subtotal_new
  FROM profile_visits AS v GROUP BY v.visitor_id) AS t
```

The `SUM()` of the inner query counts new visits *per visitor*.  The `SUM()` of the outer query gives the total new visits *for all visitors*.

Comment: Allow me to correct myself, I was actually using `SUM(v.time > 1300000012)` and that returns 4 (COUNT returns 6), but I need to get only distinct visitors, since 1300000012 there was one visit from visitor_id 8 and 3 visits from visitor_id 9, but that should count as 2 new visitors.

Comment: I ended up using a bit modified your solution: `SELECT COUNT(t.visitor_id) AS total, SUM(t.subtotal_new) AS total_new
FROM (SELECT v.visitor_id, (MAX(v.time) > 1300000012) AS subtotal_new
  FROM profile_visits v WHERE v.user_id = 1 GROUP BY v.visitor_id) AS t`

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood your requirements, but I'm glad if I helped you find the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from

((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT v.visitor_id)  
FROM profile_visits v WHERE v.user_id = 1) AS total,

(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT v.visitor_id)  
FROM profile_visits v WHERE v.time > 1300000012 and v.user_id = 1) AS new) AS Result
```